# How can i add a custom hostname to a web app in azure with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I need to add a custom domain name to a web app in azure with Terraform. I have tried some online documentation but i cant get those to work

Comment: You have to provide you TF code and explain exactly what "cant get those to work" means. Also a link to " online documentation" would be helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to get more information to be able to help you. If you don't want to expand your question with any relevant details or code examples, then that's fine.

Comment: i worked it out myself

Comment: While a source sample might not have been provided - this is the exact question I had. Hashicorps docs arent the best so I'm not suprised that @itye1970 struggled.  And good job figuring it out yourself and providing the community your solution.   Much appreciated.

Comment: @Marcin No need for a code sample. The question is very clear.

Answer (score 2):

To add an existing certificate stored in a keyvault in azure to an azure web app and add a custom domain , the following code will work

STEP 1 : declare where you keyvault is in Azure

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "azure_kv" {
  name                = "keyvaultname"
  resource_group_name = "keyvaultresourcegroupname"
}
```

STEP 2 Define the certificate you need to use from the above keyvault

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "example" {
  name         = "nameofcertificateinkeyvault"
}
```

STEP 3 - Get the certificate thumbprint from the vault
This value will be used in the Step 4 below

```
output "certificate_thumbprint" {
  value = data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.thumbprint
}
```

STEP 4 Add your custom domain name and add certificate

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding" "app_binding" {
  hostname            = "abc.co.uk"  #whatever your custom hostname is"
  app_service_name    = "webapp1"    #what your web app is called 
  resource_group_name = "webappresourcegroupname" #resource group name og your web app
  ssl_state           = "SniEnabled" #ssl status this example uses sni enabled check for what you require!
  thumbprint          =  data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.thumbprint : the value we got from STEP 3 above
  }
```

Comment: I didnt need the output for the cert thumbprint.  Just setup the certificate data resource and reference the thumbprint in the hostname binding.